# make DotLess parse CSS files instead of LESS files

Tags: css, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke, dotless

Can I get DotLess to parse all my CSS files, (which may or may not include LESS code) instead of having to include .less files in my project? I am using DotNetNuke, and would love to just start adding LESS code to my existing CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it but I imagine you could change the type piece in your HTTP handlers.

Instead of path="*.LESS" change it to path="*.CSS"

Not sure if that would work or break something but it would be interesting to see if it would.

Comment: doing this just makes the server give a 500 error. I'm sure this is on the right track, but obviously there is some non-obvious configuration needed to get this working.

Comment: @joshlfisher, can you show more info about 500 error? I use `path="*.css"` for dotLess handler in web.config file instead `path="*.less"` and it is working without any errors.